# Software and hardware communications

Tags: operating-systems, software-engineering

When you install an OS on a piece of hardware such as a Macbook, what is happening logically? In other words, how does the software "talk" to the hardware? Is it the same logical process with every OS and every piece of hardware, or is this process different for each OS and each piece of hardware?

Comment: This is a very broad question. I suggest you look at a textbook on computer architecture, or some lecture notes from an undergrad course with a similar name. Any answer to your question is likely to be at least a chapter or two of one of those books.